# In Ruby, can I reference a lambda defined in another file?

Tags: ruby, lambda, scope, visibility

I moved my lambda add_links_to_descriptions from file A to file B, but now I'm getting an error from file A:

> undefined local variable or method `add_links_to_descriptions' for main:Object (NameError)

Is there a way to fix this?

This is file A:

```
gallery = ViewableGallery.new(gallery_config.title, gallery_config.description, gallery_config.slug, \
  gallery_config.sources, gallery_config.upload_date, gallery_config.map_url, gallery_config.map_title, \
  gallery_config.year, viewable_photos).
  update_using( \
    add_tabs_before_every_description_line(2), \
    add_links_to_descriptions, \
    for_each_photo(&add_tabs_before_every_description_line(3)), \
    for_each_photo(&add_links_to_descriptions), \
    for_each_photo(&remove_final_empty_line))
```

And this is file B:

```
def add_tabs_before_every_description_line(how_many_tabs)
  return lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
    mutable_viewable_content.description = add_tabs_before_every_line(mutable_viewable_content.description, how_many_tabs)
return mutable_viewable_content
  end
end

add_links_to_descriptions = lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
  mutable_viewable_content.description = add_links_to_sources(mutable_viewable_content.description)
  return mutable_viewable_content
end
```

so add_tabs_before_every_description_line us referenced fine, I'm assuming because it's a method.
 But the lambda add_links_to_descriptions is not visible.

Comment: There should be a way to fix it, but you'll have to show some code.  Without knowing what classes, namespaces, other scopes you have, it's impossible to take a good guess.

Comment: Done. As a Ruby noob, I am not using namespaces, didn't get that far in the book yet. :)

Comment: Is it possible that `A` gets loaded before `B`?

Comment: It is A that is runnable, yes.

Comment: Then make sure you require B first. If B is not loaded, the `add_links_to_descriptions` variable is not initialized before A needs it.

Comment: So are variables treated differently to methods? How do I make sure it's loaded first? I am using require_relative.

Comment: No, they should be treated the same way. Use `require_relative "B"` before you try to access the methods/objects defined in B. Also, make sure that a method called `add_tabs_before_every_description_line` is not already loaded from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables starting with lowercase letters are *local variables*. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in (that's why they are called "local" variables).

In your example, `add_links_to_descriptions` is local to the script `B.rb`, it can only be accessed within the script scope of `B.rb`.

You have to use something other than a local variable: an instance variable of the object that is trying to call the lambda, a method of an object that is accessible to the object trying to call the lambda, a constant, a global variable are some of the possibilities. Which one of those is the "right one" depends on the overall design of your project.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. I guess it's time to read about scopes and modules etc.